# Chrome - unprompted auto-download of files after opening the browser - bug or something else?

Tags: security, chrome-for-android, browser, downloading

Upon opening google chrome on android, it suddenly downloaded (unprompted by me) a jpeg, as well as a "seed" file. 
After scanning both files with the mobile version of kaspersky, i opened the jpeg file and noticed that i knew the picture from somewhere.
Upon searching, i found it, along with the seed file in the download folder (from within the chrome app). Both were however said to be downloaded in 2017.
In contrast, in my own download folder inside the file manager the files are said to be downloaded today.

Now, what could have caused said (re-)download? Was this simply a bug, or might there be something else wrong with my phone?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend running a scan with Lookout just in case it is a virus that is initiating these downloads (I do see you've used Kaspersky so it should be fine if it didn't sound any alarms). However, it's likely a glitch with the Download Manager; I've been getting random redownloads of files that I've downloaded before through Chrome as well. A reinstall of Chrome and clearing the cache of the Files app may help, as well as a restart of the Android device.

Just the other day my Download Manager decided to "redownload" everything in my Downloads folder, yet it didn't download them in the sense that it retook them from the Internet. I think it was just reloading the files because there were no duplicates. It's likely nothing you need to worry about.