# Chrome (Android) auto download pdf every week (is it a virus ?)

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading, virus

A year ago i've been fighting against an hacker that had access to a lot of my accounts (not very difficult since my passwords were record with google account). Somehow he archives to get the codes from 2FA on my phone. I guess he had infected my phone as well (dunno if he infected my PC or my phone first and if he archieve to infect both threw one). I decided to reinstall android. Now as a 2FA i'm using authenticator app from google. Since that time, I also reinstall windows on my PC to be 100% safe. I obviously changed all my passwords since that time, multiple times.

I received a month ago an alert from microsoft saying that someone break in (again). So I changed the passwords (again). Im weakly checking connexions. Hackers are still trying but for now they just could not break the password.

But more recently, I've notice chrome app autodownloading a PDF once or two a week. I dont have any tab open to the domain where it comes from, it never ask where i want to store the file even when I enable this parameters. The file is called **reaching-all-learners.pdf** and come from this link : https://education-static.apple.com/product/reaching-all-learners.pdf
**BE CAREFUL ABOUT THE LINK** since I dont really know what is the matter with this site and how legit it is or not.

I'm wondering if any of you, with cyber knowledge could tell me what is going on and how I can fix it so it stop download this file again and over again.

I've ben looking on internet and no one looks having the issue. I have run couples of antimalware process (malwarebytes and the default security app from android) and nothing have been founded.

Thanks for taking the time to read me .

Comment: The download link is legit from Apple, at least nothing to be worried about the file. Also, probably related: [Chrome - unprompted auto-download of files after opening the browser - bug or something else?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210369/44325)

Comment: Are you sure it is legit from apple ? Because the education-static.apple.com is kinda weird. Yeah i'm gonna take a look to the thread ! Thanks !

Comment: It's one of the subdomains of `apple.com`, that one is related for [Apple Education](https://www.apple.com/education/). The file is like a brochure for [the webinar with the same name by Apple](https://events.apple.com/content/events/conferences/au/en/multiday-event.html?token=xww6uj7woR0X9A3Y8qYOQkVVdH60MurN7MAvJSY75sHQxWqaTEhMjEmalXqC7MMJuZhb5crVxf5sKUXGDQ_UXlJXtvVfbeOSca2wjYDoLAT3veT0GUZBqqvWMff6xTLhRw&a=1&l=e).